# Different results in different folders with the same commands

Tags: ios, reactjs, react-native

When I run `react-native init project` in a one folder, I am unable to run the project (I get error Print: Entry, ":CFBundleIdentifier", Does Not Exist). **However**, *in my Desktop folder*, when I do the exact same thing (`react-native init project` then `react-native run-ios`) I get no errors at all.

Why might this be happening?

Comment: Possible that permission isn't granted on the folder. In your finder, right click the folder and click `Get Info`. Down button unlock it with the lock icon & give everyone `Read & Write`. Then in the drop down gear, `Apply to enclosed items...`.

Comment: @MattyK14 Unfortunately that didn't solve it

Comment: Try a chmod 777 on the folder.

Comment: There's a lot that could be causing issues as the answers and comments already point out. To help figure out what is happening, you'll probably need to edit your question with *at least*: OS (I assume macOS but which version?), full paths to the folders, permissions of said folders, examples of the commands you're running, and npm, node, react-native versions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you have spaces in the project directory path?

- yes: try to remove spaces from directory path.
- no: try to clear cache: 
  `rm ~/.rncache` and see if it helps.

If it does not help, take a look at https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/14423

Comment: What will removing ~/.rncache actually do?

Answer (score 0):

Please look at the following page and search for "CFBundleIdentifier": https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/CoreFoundationKeys.html

The problem seems to be in the path which might have *non-roman* characters. Maybe the issue is not even the current folder name but perhaps in a parent folder (in the full path directory).

From the linked documentation:

> An identifier string that specifies the app type of the bundle. The
>   string should be in reverse DNS format using only the Roman alphabet
>   in upper and lower case (A–Z, a–z), the dot (“.”), and the hyphen
>   (“-”)

More details: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/CoreFoundationKeys.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20001431-102070